# colorbox leave behind page on iframe close or back button

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Hoping someone can help me.  I am using [colorbox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) to pop open an `<iframe>` form when a user submits their zip code.  There is one additional event I would like to happen only when a user attempts to close the iframe or hits back on their browser.  In either of these events, I would like the parent page (the page under the iframe) to load a different page url.  Currently the code I am using to pop open the iframe on zip code submit is the following:

```
<script> 
function submitHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
         var zip = $('#zip').val();
         if (zip.length < 5) { alert("Please enter a valid zip code"); return false;};
         //alert("keyword is " + keyword);
    $.colorbox({href: "/ppc/form.htm?zip=" + zip, iframe:true, innerWidth:800, innerHeight:600});
}

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('form#start').submit(function(e) {
        submitHandler(e);
    });

    $("a[rel=zipformSubmit]").click(function(e) { 
        submitHandler(e);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.colorbox(
    {
        href: "/ppc/form.htm?zip=" + zip, iframe:true,nnerWidt ih:800, innerHeight:600,
        onClosed:function(){window.location = "http://www.google.com";}
    }
);
```

Comment: i just edited my post ! change `$.colorbox({href: "/ppc/form.htm?zip=" + zip, iframe:true, innerWidth:800, innerHeight:600});` , with this code , `"url"` to ur different page

Comment: {href: "/ppc/form.htm?zip=" + zip, iframe:true, innerWidth:800, innerHeight:600, onClosed:function(){window.location.location = "http://www.google.com";}...tried that and no luck

Comment: i have this now with no luck:          $.colorbox(
       {
        href: "/ppc/form.htm?zip=" + zip, iframe:true, innerWidth:800, innerHeight:600, 
        onClosed:function(){window.location.location = "http://www.google.com";}
     }
    );

Comment: that works--thank you.  Do you also know how to make the parent page load http://www.google.com behind the lightbox when the iframe initially loads instead of when the iframe is closed?